# Find TH object (table head) by text using jquery without iterating over all TH's of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically created HTML table clicking on its TH will reload the table according to sorted column.

What i want is to apply a class to the TH clicked.

Since the table is reloaded i first put the clicked column name in a Global variable and then when the table get reloaded i want to apply a CSS class.

The requirement is i want to search the THs in a TR by text (without iterating all elements) and then apply a class.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

EDIT:

We cannot use :contains becuase two column names can contains similar text header

Comment: May be we can use jquery find by dont know how.

Comment: What is `without iterating all elements`? Not iterating all table rows, all table headers, all table cells, no iterating at all?

Comment: @mrtsherman without iterating all TH

Comment: How are you supposed to search the th's without iterating over them? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you select it by column number instead?

Comment: @mrtsherman by iterating means i dont want to use some for loops for the same. hoping there might be some other solution like built in method or so on id i am right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function allows you to specify a function to be used as the filter.

```
$("th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "foo";
}).addClass("newClass");
```

Comment: This solves my problem but u mistakenly use text instead of text(). PLease correct

Answer (score 0):

To apply a class to the th when clicked:

```
$(function () {

  $('th').on('click', function () {
   $(this).addClass('myClickedClass');
  });

});
```

If you want to apply the class based on the match of a string, use this:

```
$(function () {

  $("th:contains('" + myStringValue + "')").addClass('myClickedClass');
});
```

Comment: If two column have names like id , brand_id then contains will apply classes on both if the contains value is "ID"

Comment: That is true.  Adam's solution is the correct one for exact matches.